# Close a PDF file when read it from java

Tags: java, file, pdf, pdfbox

I am reading some text from a pdf file

```
try { 
    File pdfFile = new File("ffile.pdf");
    PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(pdfFile));     
    parser.parse();
    COSDocument cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
    //do sth

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document."
                    + e.getMessage());
}
```

and some times I get this error:

```
WARNING [Finalizer] org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.finalize Warning: You did not close a PDF Document
```

I read a similar qustion here where it says I have to close the opened file. So, I added

```
finally{
    pdfFile.close();  //<-
}
```

but Netbeans mark it with error the `close()` saying that can't find symbol.
So what I have to close? I tried also `parser.close()` but this line is also marked with error from Netbeans.

Comment: what is it you try to close, and what name did you give it in your code?

Comment: I want to close the file I loaded, which is `pdfFile`

Comment: You need to close the COSDocument, not the parser.

Comment: @bmargulies you are right! It worked. Post it as an answer to take the credits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `close()` method of the [`PDDocument`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#close()) or the [`COSDocument`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/cos/COSDocument.html#close()) instance (in both cases the `close` method of the `COSDocument` object is called)

Comment: you mean `cosDoc.close();`

Comment: @Nat95: That would be the code to use. I guess I there was need to rephrase the answer...

Answer (score 2):

You are using an outdated way to open files. This is the correct way to do it (exception handling omitted):

```
File pdfFile = new File("ffile.pdf");
PDDocument pdDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
//....
pdDoc.close();
```

Comment: A lot simpler and shorter!